# Standard error higher than coefficient and SE of regression

Tags: regression, standard-error

I am having some problems with my regression where the SE is higher than the coefficient and sometimes even larger than the SE of regression. I am wondering what might be the underlying problem or is there an explanation to this. [image: This is meant to show the effect of venture capital investment on real GDP/capita]
[image: this is meant to show interaction variable of R&D and GDP on total factor productivity]
Clarification on this matter would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

There is not necessarily a problem if the standard error is greater than the value of the coefficient. All it means is that when you compute a confidence interval for the coefficient then for most choices of the confidence coefficient the lower limit will be less than zero. Of course if the outcome variable with which you are dealing is inherently positive (like a count for example) then your model is mis--specified and you need to change it.

You will need to clarify what the book defines as the standard error of the regression. I assume this is the standard error of estimate. This is something completely different.

Comment: I was also wondering whether it was meant to be SE of estimates which is the regression coefficients. This test was run on gretl rather than my normal Eviews. I do understand that premise of the SE theory but I am just baffled by the magnitude of it and am unsure on how to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

If your standard error for a specific variable is noticeably (much) larger than for other variables, I suggest you take a closer look at that variable. One explanation could be that you have very few values in that variable, another possible reason could be outlier/s (extremely high or low values that scew the data).

If you have few values in your variable you can't really do anything about it, other than bring it up and emphasize that the estimate should not be considered significant (providing that it really isn't of course).

If you have outlier/s you just want to make sure that they are not due to mistakes, e.g. 999999.